# Shouldn't VARCHAR data be converted to char * (MSSQL OLE DB)?

Tags: c++, sql-server, oledb

In a C++ program, I am trying to read data from MSSQL database using OLE DB. The column I am trying to read is a VARCHAR type. The data in the column is imported from a multi-value database. Sometimes the data in the column has a delimiter in it. The delimiter is a value marker (0Xfd). I covert the data read from the table to a char * like this:

```
retcode = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, (WCHAR*)pDBColumnAccess[nCol].pData, -1, (char *)pReadBuf, pDBColumnAccess[nCol].cbDataLen, NULL, NULL);
```

Everything is fine if the data does not contain above mentioned delimiter - value marker (0xfd). But when the delimiter is there, in the converted data the value marker is replaced by some junk characters.

Shouldn't I do a conversion to char * in the case of VARCHAR? Is it enough to just copy the data as it is without any coversion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `WideCharToMultiByte` converts from UTF-16, yet there is no such thing as `0xFD` character in UTF-16. All characters are encoded as at least 2 bytes. Did you actually mean `0x00FD` (or even `0xFD00`)?

Also, UTF-8 (your "target" encoding since you specified `CP_UTF8`) does not guarantee that all characters will be encoded in just one byte.

According to [UTF Converter](http://macchiato.com/unicode/convert.html):

- UTF-16 `00FD` converts to UTF-8 `C3 BD`.
- UTF-16 `FD00` converts to UTF-8 `EF B4 80`.

Is that what you are getting?

Comment: The UTF Converter is very useful, thanks for the reply and the link. I acutually meant 0x00FD.